# How can I use background-color : WindowInfoBackground?

Tags: css

I am trying to use `background-color : WindowInfoBackground;`.

> `background-color : WindowInfoBackground;` assigns the operating
>   system color to `background-color`

When I use this value, my element background color does not change.

Comment: What colour do you expect `WindowInfoBackground` to be?

Comment: My operation system color, and I don't know this color.

Comment: It's probably white...

Comment: @fateme why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://nscraps.com/CSS/1333-what-is-css-windowinfobackground-color.htm:

> The WindowInfoBackground function is the function used to set the background color of a window assigns operating system color which is normally be White in color and is considered to be equal to background-color:white; or equal to background-color:rgb(100%,100%,100%); or equal to background-color:rgb(255,255,255); or equal to background-color:WindowInfoBackground;

If your elements `background-color` is white then changing it to `background-color:WindowInfoBackground;` will probably keep it white.